# Getting null in display name and email just after using first time in apple sign in

Tags: flutter, apple-sign-in

While using apple sign in every thing is fine till first time. After this I'm not able to get email  and display name. Well I'm not able to understand what is the problem.

here is my code

````
String generateNonce([int length = 32]) {
    final charset =
        '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._';
    final random = Random.secure();
    return List.generate(length, (_) => charset[random.nextInt(charset.length)])
        .join();
  }

  /// Returns the sha256 hash of [input] in hex notation.
  String sha256ofString(String input) {
    final bytes = utf8.encode(input);
    final digest = sha256.convert(bytes);
    return digest.toString();
  }

final rawNonce = generateNonce();
    final nonce = sha256ofString(rawNonce);

final appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
        scopes: [
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
        ],
        nonce: nonce,
      );

final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
        idToken: appleCredential.identityToken,
        rawNonce: rawNonce,
      );

final authResult =
          await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);

return authResult;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link We only get one time request for security and their privacy reasons. So, we need to save the user info in cache or device keychain to retrive it back.
Link: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121496.

[sign_in_with_apple](https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple) dependcy itself includes support for keychain entries

If you fails in storing "**email**", "**firstname**" first time, then you should follow the following steps:

**iPhone Settings -> Apple Id -> Password & Security -> Apple ID logins -> YOUR APP > Stop using Apple ID.**